# Do I need the Default Document IIS7 role installed for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

Do i need this role installed if I wish to have a website that is running ASP.NET MVC?

[image]

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you shouldn't need it as the MVC routing engine should take care of all of this for you.